# Why won't tf.write_file write a file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, cleverhans

My code is:

```
i = 0
fgsm = FastGradientMethod(wrap)
adv = fgsm.generate(x_test_tensor, **fgsm_params)

for adv_x in tf.unstack(adv):
    img = tf.cast(adv_x, dtype=tf.uint8)
    tf_image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(img)
    tf.write_file('adversarial_examples/' + str(i) + '.jpg', tf_image)
    i += 1
```

Where FastGradientMethod is from `cleverhans`. This runs without an error, but the jpg's don't exist in my folder. What's missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may the path of the destination file is not correct

```
import os

for adv_x in tf.unstack(adv):
    img = tf.cast(adv_x, dtype=tf.uint8)
    tf_image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(img)
    pth = os.path.join('adversarial_examples', '%s.jpg'%i)
    tf.write_file(pth, tf_image)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you should:

```
op = tf.write_file(pth, tf_image)
sess.run(op)
```

Where `sess` is a `tf.session`.